# How to use behaviors in Universal Windows Platform?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, blend

I'm trying to add behaviors for my card game, but don't understand how to use them in proper way - where to put the behavior etc.
I have a listbox of cards (cards are loaded from images) and want to move card up when its clicked and move down when its clicked again.
Can anyone suggest me guide on how to use behaviors in UWP apps or give me an example on my code ( which is not working:( ).

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard1" >

    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>


<ListView x:Name="list" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="50,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick" >
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,-70,0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="100"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="68"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter>
                            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="GotFocus">

                                    <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}">

                                    </media:ControlStoryboardAction>
                                </interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </ListViewItemPresenter>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListViewItem>

    </ListViewItem>

    <Image x:Name="One" MaxWidth="68" Height="100" >
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>

                <media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard1}">

                </media:ControlStoryboardAction>
            </interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Image>
    <Image x:Name="Two" MaxWidth="68" Height="100" />
    <Image x:Name="Three" MaxWidth="68" Height="100" />
</ListView>
```

Comment: I don't understand about "move card up when its clicked and move down when its clicked again", you want to move the image from where to where? up where, down where?

Comment: Try to replace your `<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>`
into `DataTemplate` for your `ListView`.